# What is the difference between intermediate and terminal operations?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

can someone tell me What is the difference between intermediate and terminal operations for `Stream`?

`Stream` operations are combined into pipelines to process streams. All operations are either intermediate or terminal ..means?.

Comment: streams are lazy , code actually do something when a terminal operation is invoked like sum , toarray etc and  filter , map are intermediate , probably a dupe

Answer (score 84, accepted):

A Stream supports several operations and these operations are divided into `intermediate` and `terminal` operations.

The distinction between this operations is that an intermediate operation is lazy while a terminal operation is not. When you invoke an intermediate operation on a stream, the operation is not executed immediately. It is executed only when a terminal operation is invoked on that stream. In a way, an intermediate operation is memorized and is recalled as soon as a terminal operation is invoked. You can chain multiple intermediate operations and none of them will do anything until you invoke a terminal operation. At that time, all of the intermediate operations that you invoked earlier will be invoked along with the terminal operation.

All intermediate operations return Stream (can be chained), while terminal operations don't. Intermediate Operations are:

```
filter(Predicate<T>)
map(Function<T>)
flatMap(Function<T>)
sorted(Comparator<T>)
peek(Consumer<T>)
distinct()
limit(long n)
skip(long n)
```

Terminal operations produces a non-stream (cannot be chained) result such as primitive value, a collection or no value at all.

Terminal Operations are:

```
forEach
forEachOrdered
toArray
reduce
collect
min
max
count
anyMatch
allMatch
noneMatch
findFirst    
findAny
```

Last 5 are short-circuiting terminal operations.

Answer (score 14):

As per [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

- **Intermediate operation** will transform a stream into another stream, such as `map(MapperFn)` or `filter(Predicate)`
- **Terminal operation** will produce a result or side-effect, such as `count()` or `forEach(Consumer)`

Note that all intermediate operations will **NOT** be executed without a terminal operation at the end. So the pattern will be:

```
stream()
    .intemediateOperation1()
    .intemediateOperation2()
    ...
    .intemediateOperationN()
    .terminalOperation();
```

Answer (score 5):

Terminal meaning ending the process, such as collecting a stream to a list, or aggregating a stream of values.

Intermediate as in transitioning to a new state, on the way to a terminal operation

Comment: Does it caches any data?

Comment: No, they don't. Where are you seeing that they do?

Answer (score 2):

You probably noticed that when you define a stream, the methods aren't just called one by one on the whole stream, but rather they do something on each element from the stream. To be able to run these streams in parallel, for every element, there is basically a whole pipeline.

In order to create multiple pipelines, Java 8+ uses the [builder pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder). With every intermediate step you add a filter or converter to the stack. In order to tell Java to generate pipelines from that stack of filters, you use a terminating step. That last step combines all the different pipelines. Usually it just returns the values in a defined format, e.g. a list, but it can also run a function once for each element, or reduce the results to a boolean or a number.

Answer (score 2):

To visualize let's take this code:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        int sum = numbers.stream()
                .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
                .map(n -> n * n)
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

`filter` and `map` are intermediate operations, `reduce` is terminal.

1. We create a stream from List (`numbers.stream()`), so we have:
   |1,2,3,4|
2. filter values (`numbers.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)`):
   |1,2,3,4| ----- |filter|
3. Map (`numbers.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).map(n -> n * n)`):
   |1,2,3,4| ----- |filter| ----- |map|
4. finally we call `reduce`, which is terminal operation and the whole flow runs:
   |1,2,3,4| -> 4 3 2 1 -> |filter| -> 4 2 -> |map| -> 16 4 -> |reduce| -> 20

Notice that no data flows through the stream until the terminal operation is called.