# Applying changes over other objects using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm learning about Java 8 streams API by trying different examples. I'm trying to form a HashMap from an ArrayList using streams .map() method. (I know about .groupingBy method but i am trying to understand the underlying logic of stream operations.) When i run my code without calling the forEach() method (or any terminal operation) changes are not being applied to my HashMap<> and it stays empty. But calling a terminal operation enable to protect changes i made. I was thinking that terminal operations used only to return non-stream values and end streams. Can anyone explain why this is happening like this ?

class Main {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a list of arrays then form a HasMap based on entries of list
    List<String[]> list3 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] entry1 = {"a","b","c"};
    String[] entry2 = {"d","e","f"};
    String[] entry3 = {"g","h","i"};
    list3.add(entry1);
    list3.add(entry2);
    list3.add(entry3);

    // hashmap
    HashMap<String, String[]> map1 = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

    // streamize the list to form hashmap
    list3.stream()
         .map(entry ->  {
                            String key = entry[0];
                            String[] value = {entry[1],entry[2]};
                            map1.put(key, value);
                            // must return a String[]
                            return entry;
                        })
         // CHANGES ARE ONLY APPLIED WHEN TERMINAL OPERATIONS CALLED ???
         .forEach(entry -> {});

    // print elements
    for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
```

}

// Without terminal op

```
                              //Empty
```

// With terminal op

a=[Ljava.lang.String;@7921b0a2

d=[Ljava.lang.String;@174d20a

g=[Ljava.lang.String;@66d2e7d9

Comment: nothing is done without ta terminal operation - as simple as that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between intermediate and terminal operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688418/what-is-the-difference-between-intermediate-and-terminal-operations)

Comment: Streams are lazy, they won't process more than their terminal operation require. Good examples are `anyMatch()` and such were the operation will stop at the first positive

Comment: Also, don't make an habit of coding side-effects into a `map`, that step should be pure

Comment: So i better look for understanding lazy methods first i guess ?

Comment: So why are you using `map` when you do not intent to *map* elements to other elements, but rather perform an action per element? Why don’t you write that action into the consumer passed to `forEach` and get rid of the obsolete `map` step? Of course, a real Stream solution, i.e. `Map<String, String[]> map1 = list3.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> new String[] { a[1], a[2] }));` would be better, but *if* you need to perform an action, use the method intended to perform an action.

Comment: @MertBeşiktepe "lazy" can be used in multiple ways in programming, but it generally means avoiding to do work you might not require. With streams it means they won't process their whole datasource's content but only as much as their terminal operation requires. If it's `forEach` they must process all the datasource, but if it's `findFirst` they can stop once they've reached the first non-filtered element.

Comment: Thanks for clarfication! Your last comment would be a good answer to this question i think. I was imagining that map is for applying a function element-wise on stream real misunderstanding originates from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is good to note that the main reason why your `HashMap` is not filled, is because your code is put into the body of a [lambda expression](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html). A lambda is similar to an anonymous inner class:

```
jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

If you define something like this, the method `doSomething()` is not instantly executed, instead, the `addActionListener` method stores the `ActionListener` instance somewhere as a instance variable, so it can be used later. That means you're effectlively only defining a method, but you're not calling it yet.

The `map` method of the `Stream` interface (whichever implementation you're using) accepts an instance of `Function`, which is only a definition. It only stores this `Function` somewhere, but does not execute the body of your lambda expression.

`Stream` implementations are lazy. The're designed to do nothing until they absolutely have to. That is only the case when the caller actually *need* some result (i.e. collect).

Once you call a terminal operation, *then* the Stream implementation will actually apply all necessary transformation and filtering steps, and return some form of result.

**Related:**

- [What is the difference between intermediate and terminal operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47693257/507738)

---

*Note: stream operations should not have side effects. That means that you should avoid doing things like `map1.put(key, value)`.*

Comment: Thank you for your time i understand the logic behind it better now !