# Why stream peek does not work properly in HashMap

Tags: java, java-stream

```
HashMap<Long, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
// here init map, add some values there

// with 'foreach' all elements are printed
map.entrySet().stream().foreach(System.out::println);

// but when I use 'peek' nothing happens
map.entrySet().stream().peek(System.out::println);
```

My question is: why `peek` does not iterate all elements from the stream?

Comment: You may also want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688418/what-is-the-difference-between-intermediate-and-terminal-operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`peek` is an intermediate `Stream` operation, and therefore it is lazily evaluated.

Your pipeline has no terminal operation, so `peek` is never evaluated.

If you add a terminal operation, such as `collect(Collectors.toList())`, `peek` will be executed for all the elements required to perform the terminal operation, which in this example happens to be all the elements of the `Stream`:

```
map.entrySet().stream().peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList());
```