# Java Streams : Using println with map and forEach

Tags: java, java-stream

I started working with streams and facing below issue:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
al.add(10);
al.add(20);
al.add(30);

al.stream().forEach(System.out::println); // This works

al.stream().map(System.out::println); // This fails with error as "Incompatible types: expected not void but compile-time declaration for method reference has void return type"
```

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: `map` takes a `Function` that transforms the stream's element type into something else. Can the `void`-returning `println` do that?

Comment: ```map``` expects a function. ```System.out.println()``` is a consumer and not a function

Comment: `map` returns a value. So it accepts a function that returns a value. System.out.println() doesn't return anything.

Comment: Or, in even simpler words, it's because `map` is a different method than `forEach`, with an entirely different purpose and no reason to behave like `forEach`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a plain English kind of way:

`forEach` applies a method that has a side effect to each element of your stream, it is a [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688418/what-is-the-difference-between-intermediate-and-terminal-operations) operation and it does not return anything:

```
...
.forEach(thisElement -> doThatWith(thisElement))
```

examples:

```
.forEach(thisElement -> System.out.println(thisElement))
.forEach(thisElement -> aList.add(thisElement))
```

`map` applies a method that transform each element of your stream into another object and returns a `Stream<NewObjectClass>`:

```
...
.map(thisElement -> transformIntoAnotherElement(thisElement))
```

Examples:

```
.map(thisElement -> String.valueOf(thisElement)) // returns Stream<String>
.map(thisElement -> new MyObject(thisElement)) // returns Stream<MyObject>
```

Answer (score 2):

`map()` transforms a `Stream` of elements of one type to a `Stream` of elements of another type.

Therefore, you must pass to `map()` a `Function` that transforms elements of the original type to the new type. `System.out::println` doesn't fit the `Function` functional interface, since it has a `void` return type.

And even if you passed a valid `Function` to `map()`, it would not be applied to any elements of the `Stream`, since your second `Stream` pipeline has no terminal operation.