# Difference between map and forEach for instance modification

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

When I run the code below, StringBuilder instance remains empty.

```
String[] params = {"v1", "v2"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Stream.of(params).map(param -> sb.append(param));
```

However, when I run the same code with forEach instead of map, it behaves as expected (appends array elements to StringBuilder instance):

```
String[] params = {"v1", "v2"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Stream.of(params).forEach(param -> sb.append(param));
```

Why doesn't it change StringBuilder in the first example?

Comment: `map` is an intermediary operation, while `forEach` is a terminal operation. Since `Stream`s are evaluated lazily, the intermediary operations are ony triggered thtrough a terminal operation.

Comment: [What is the difference between intermediate and terminal operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688418/what-is-the-difference-between-intermediate-and-terminal-operations)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Stream`s are evaluated lazily](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html). This means that [intermediate operations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) like [`Stream::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) and [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) are only evaluated when they are triggered through a terminal operation like [`Stream::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) or [`Stream::collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

We can rewrite the code to make it behave as expected:

```
String[] params = {"v1", "v2"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Stream.of(params).map(sb::append).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Kucd4H)

I would, however, suggest to use the `forEach`-example presented in the post, since this reflects the semantics of the code in a concise and clear way.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the stream has not been invoked.

```
String[] params = {"v1", "v2"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Stream.of(params).map(param -> sb.append(param));
```

The last statement doesn't run since there is no subsequent method that activates the stream.  Try this:

```
Stream.of(params).map(param -> sb.append(param)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Now `sb` should have the values.

Comment: Thank you!
Sorry but Turing85 answered first (in the comments).

Comment: Quite alright!  The important thing is that you got your answer.